# Creating an array of Class objects and printing them in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering is it possible to put this into an array so that it would print the same thing three times?

```
ChineseFireball dragon = ChineseFireball("Scarlet", "Beast", "China", 6, 25);

dragon.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Populate */
ChineseFireball dragons[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dragons[i] = ChineseFireball("Scarlet", "Beast", "China", 6, 25);
}

/* Print */
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dragons[i].print();
}
```

if array is not necessary:

```
ChineseFireball dragon = ChineseFireball("Scarlet", "Beast", "China", 6, 25);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dragon.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is how:

```
ChineseFireball dragons[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dragons[i] = ChineseFireball("Scarlet", "Beast", "China", 6, 25);
}
```

And then to print, simply loop through the `dragons` array and call `print()` on each element.

That's assuming you want to have three `dragons`. If you simply want to execute `print()` on the single `dragon` instance three times, run it in a loop like the one above.